# How can I get dynamic API name in apex?

Tags: apex, reflection

I have an question,I created a FieldSet named Detailed_Content in several sObjects,now I want get one of sObjects's Detailed_Content FieldSet,like the following code:

```
public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getDetailed_ContentFields() {
    return SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.Detailed_Content.getFields();
}
```

the question is,can I dynamicly create the sObject's API name,replacing the uppter code's static 'Account'?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

yes, you can. Use [`Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm) method that accepts String as API name of object

```
List<Schema.FieldSetMember> f = Schema.getGlobalDescribe()
    .get(objectName)
    .getDescribe()
    .fieldSets
    .getMap()
    .get('Detailed_Content')
    .getFields();
```

Comment: It works! Thanks very much! It botherd me a whole atfernoon.Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Type.forName to get the SObjectType, and from there, you can describe it:

```
Schema.FieldSetMember[] f = ((SObject)Type.forName('Schema.Account')
  .newInstance()).getSObjectType().getDescribe()
  .fieldSets.getMap().get('Detailed_Content').fields();
```

This has a slight timing advantage over calling getGlobalDescribe in large orgs.